# Eliminar funcion default de boton y asignarle otra que permita retroceder a la pagina anterior

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un boton que me deberia regresar a la pagina anterior sin embargo me envia a un submit, funcion que la tiene otro boton y ni idea xq este la tiene tambien. Quiero quitarle la funcion por default y asignarle que regrese a la pagina anterior con un onclick. Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma pero sencillamente al boton ya no hace nada.

```
    $('.regresar').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        history.back();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los botones no tienen 'acción por defecto'. Aunque si pueden provocar un envio de formulario si este pertenece a un `form` y esta marcado con atributo `type="submit"` en vez de `type="button"`

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de un formulario con dos botones, uno marcado como `submit` y otro como `button`. Ambos realizarán el envió de formulario. Uno de ellos de forma nativa, y otro de forma programática.

También aprovechamos para ver el funcionamiento de `preventDefault`, que en este caso aplica para prevenir el envió del formulario mediante el método tradicional.

```js
(function() {

 var form = document.getElementById('myform');
 function onSubmit(event) {
      // Prevenimos el envio del formulario.
     if (event) { event.preventDefault(); }
     console.log('submitted');
 }
 form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit, false);
 form.submit = onSubmit;       // Notese que obSubmit queda anclado a form.submit, no a button.click
 console.log(urlEncodeFormData(form));

 function urlEncodeFormData(form) {
     var i, e, data = [];
     for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
         e = form.elements[i];
         if (e.type !== 'button' && e.type !== 'submit') {
          data.push(encodeURIComponent(e.id) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(e.value)); 
         }
     };
     return data.join('&');
 }

})();
```

```html
<form id="myform">
    Name: <input id="name" type="text" value="dperezv" /><br />
    Email: <input id="email" type="text" value="job@dperezv.com" /><br />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">type=submit</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="form.submit()">form.submit()</button>
</form>
```